# angular form validation and pristine forms

Tags: angularjs, validation

I'm making a 'add new user' /'edit existing user' form. If the page loads and there's data in formData then I'm obviously editing an existing user and it will populate the fields as appropriate.

If the page loads with no data in formData then this is obviously a new user. If it's a new user, the fields should be empty **but they should not be showing error feedback**.

I thought that was what $pristine was for. In my example it looks look my attempt to populate the fields is triggering the $pristine = false.

How can I accommodate both scenarios?

My plunker is a bit basic. iN my app, I launch the form from a page that lists all users (click a user to edit) and also has an 'Add user ' button. This means I can load the page with or without formData populated as-needed.

http://plnkr.co/edit/WH9VQmleVQM2ELBREIYU?p=preview

I wonder if it has something to do with using two-way binding to the model?

```
    ng-model="formData.username"
    value="{{formData.username || ''}}"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They show error feedback because in your css style you defined input.ng-invalid, which is true no matter if it is pristine or not. Following should solve your problem:

```
input.ng-invalid.ng-dirty {
    border: 1px solid #a94442;
    outline: 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 8px rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.6);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 8px rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.6);
}
```